# vicon_bridge error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit OS.
I tried to run 'roslaunch vicon_bridge vicon.launch' on hydro and groovy and had the same warning/error:

INFO] [1390137222.676945590]: Connecting to Vicon DataStream SDK at 132.68.134.248:801 ...

INFO] [1390137222.677941728]: .

INFO] [1390137223.678180017]: ... connected!

INFO] [1390137223.678270448]: Setting Stream Mode to ClientPull: Success

INFO] [1390137223.678349341]: Axis Mapping: X-Forward Y-Left Z-Up

INFO] [1390137223.678407270]: Version: 1.3.0

INFO] [1390137223.678460232]: setting up grab_vicon_pose service server ...

INFO] [1390137223.679896506]: setting up segment calibration service server ...

WARN] [1390137223.682296444]: grab frame returned false

WARN] [1390137223.682608706]: TableRef occluded, not publishing...

INFO] [1390137223.682663705]: creating new object ParkourBot/ParkourBot ...

INFO] [1390137223.682870449]: creating new object TableRef2/TableRef2 ...

WARN] [1390137223.685893823]: unable to load zero pose for TableRef2/TableRef2

INFO] [1390137223.685956728]: ... done, advertised as " vicon/TableRef2/TableRef2"

WARN] [1390137223.686623200]: unable to load zero pose for ParkourBot/ParkourBot

INFO] [1390137223.686674882]: ... done, advertised as " vicon/ParkourBot/ParkourBot"

WARN] [1390137223.782380258]: TableRef occluded, not publishing...

WARN] [1390137223.882435177]: TableRef occluded, not publishing...

WARN] [1390137223.982319335]: TableRef occluded, not publishing...

WARN] [1390137224.082267703]: TableRef occluded, not publishing...

WARN] [1390137224.182242208]: TableRef occluded, not publishing...

WARN] [1390137224.282265532]: TableRef occluded, not publishing...

WARN] [1390137224.382214965]: TableRef occluded, not publishing...

Any idea how it can be fixed?
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/119466/vicon_bridge-error/) by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2014-01-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TopSecret](https://answers.ros.org/users/11111/topsecret/) on 2014-06-04**:
Did you succeeded in correcting this problem? I have the same issue right now.

**Comment by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) on 2014-09-19**:
No, I failed to solve this issue. If you  succeeded I would like to know the solution

**Comment by [Anas Alhashimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/10201/anas-alhashimi/) on 2014-12-03**:
hello,
Is it error ? or warning?
I have similar WARN, but it works pretty well!

**Comment by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) on 2014-12-16**:
I havn't tried since. It  didn't work for me.

**Comment by [Anas Alhashimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/10201/anas-alhashimi/) on 2014-12-16**:
I updated the vicon_SDK to the latest Linux version (Linux32-boost-1.53.0 and Linux64-boost-1.53.0). After rosmake, The vicon_bridge is working now and i can see the segments topics published in ROS. I have the following setup: ROS fuerte ,Ubuntu : 12.04 LTS 32-bit running on 64-bit laptop.

**Comment by [rahulROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/27667/rahulros/) on 2016-08-02**:
How did you update the vicon sdk?

**Comment by [Anas Alhashimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/10201/anas-alhashimi/) on 2016-08-03**:
I don't remember exactly. But I think you just need to extract the files into the folder vicon_sdk.

**Comment by [rahulROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/27667/rahulros/) on 2016-08-08**:
I tried deleting the old sdk and extracting the new one into the vicon_sdk folder, but catkin build would not work. It said that the Client.h file could not be located even though that it was present in the new sdk folder. If i keep the old files and extract, its the same "occluded not publishing.."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I updated the SDK files on another computer:

1. copy and extract the new SDK file (in my case it was 'Vicon_SDK_1.3_Linux.tar') to the folder vicon_sdk;
2. open the file 'CMakeLists.txt' and replace the line set(VICON_SDK     vicon_sdk/vicon_datastream_SDK_1.2.59611_x64) with       set(VICON_SDK             vicon_sdk/Vicon_SDK_1.3_Linux/Linux64-boost-1.53.0/20130523_60242h/Release)
   and set(VICON_SDK             vicon_sdk/vicon_datastream_SDK_1.2.59611_x86) with set(VICON_SDK             vicon_sdk/Vicon_SDK_1.3_Linux/Linux32-boost-1.53.0/20130524_60250h/Release);
3. rosmake

then it should be fixed ;)

---

Originally posted by [Anas Alhashimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/10201/anas-alhashimi/) with karma: 179 on 2017-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0